# Qt::Popup breaks QScroller kinetic scroll?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, touchscreen

First of all my problem is reproducible only on device with touch screen,
with PC/mouse all works fine.

The problem that if I use `QTableView` + `QScroller` as standalone window all works fine - I move finger from bottom to top content scrolls down, from top to bottom scrolls up.

But if I put `QTableView` inside `QWidget` with `Qt::Popup` attribute, then scrolling changes direction! I move finger from bottom to top and it scrolls up, from top to bottom scrolls down.

Here is my code:

```
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QScroller>
#include <QTouchDevice>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QTableView>

class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
public:
  MyModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent) {}

  int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override {
    return 100;
  }
  int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override {
    return 3;
  }
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index,
                int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override {
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
      return QString("Row%1, Column%2")
          .arg(index.row() + 1)
          .arg(index.column() + 1);
    }
    return QVariant();
  }
  QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                      int role) const override {
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
      if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
        switch (section) {
        case 0:
          return QString("first");
        case 1:
          return QString("second");
        case 2:
          return QString("third");
        }
      }
    }
    return QVariant();
  }
};

bool is_touch_screen_avaible() {
  const auto devs = QTouchDevice::devices();
  for (const auto &dev : devs) {
    if (dev->type() == QTouchDevice::TouchScreen) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void configure_scoller_for_item_view(QAbstractItemView *view) {
  QScroller *scroller = QScroller::scroller(view);
  view->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
  view->setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
  QScrollerProperties properties =
      QScroller::scroller(scroller)->scrollerProperties();
  QVariant overshootPolicy =
      QVariant::fromValue<QScrollerProperties::OvershootPolicy>(
          QScrollerProperties::OvershootAlwaysOff);
  properties.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::VerticalOvershootPolicy,
                             overshootPolicy);
  scroller->setScrollerProperties(properties);
  properties.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::HorizontalOvershootPolicy,
                             overshootPolicy);
  scroller->setScrollerProperties(properties);
  if (is_touch_screen_avaible())
    scroller->grabGesture(view, QScroller::TouchGesture);
  else
    scroller->grabGesture(view, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
}

#define POPUP

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
#ifdef POPUP
  QWidget *mainWin = new QWidget;
  mainWin->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
  auto lay = new QVBoxLayout(mainWin);
  mainWin->setLayout(lay);
  auto tableView = new QTableView(mainWin);
  lay->addWidget(tableView);
#else
  auto tableView = new QTableView;
#endif
  MyModel myModel(nullptr);
  tableView->setModel(&myModel);
  tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
  tableView->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
  configure_scoller_for_item_view(tableView);

#ifdef POPUP
  mainWin->resize(500, 500);
  mainWin->show();
#else
  tableView->resize(500, 500);
  tableView->show();
#endif

  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `QT::popup` is always `modal`, this could be the issue. while testing with `Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Tool` might provide needed functionality

Comment: Moving the finger on the tableView or the scrollbar? If on the scrollbar, Qt 5.10.1 + Win10 didn't see the issue as described...

Comment: @Jiu the tableview

Comment: I meet the similar issue before, Qt generate completed different event by touching between Freescale Yocto & Windows with the same code. I run your code in Win10+mingw, the table view even can't scroll...Better mention the device may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt doesn't fully implement gestures in scrollable areas as [explained in their own documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/ScrollGestures):

> Qt does not really reflect the system behavior wrt gestures on scrollable views (widget classes inheriting QAbstractItemView, QML classes) well.
>
> [...]
>
> In widgets, the pan recognizer is currently hard-coded to use 2 touch points. For touchscreens, it should be changed to one. But that can't be done as long as single-finger-panning is reserved for selecting text.
>
> When using a touch screen, the selection in widgets is driven by mouse events synthesized from touch by the system (Windows) or Qt itself (other platforms). The same touch events drive QGestureManager.

On the other hand, there is a [known](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html) (and [old](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtouchevent.html)) undefined behavior with `QTouchEvents` and pop-up widgets:

> The behavior of QTouchEvents is undefined when opening a pop-up or grabbing the mouse while there are more than one active touch points.

Probably the combination of both issues is the origin of your problem.

As a possible workaround (although not completely what you want), you can enable the two-fingers scroll with `QWidget::grabGesture(Qt::PanGesture)` as an alternative. Also, as mentioned by @mohammad-kanan in a comment, you may try with `Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Tool` instead of `Qt::Popup`.